# "Parsing error: Unexpected token )" with bot

Tags: scripting, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I'm trying to make a timer that every second it edits the message to time + 1 second like a real clock (Like 0:00). I'm a noob at this. This is my script:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  let timerMessage = await message.channel.send('0');

  for (i = 0, 10000000000) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      timerMessage.edit(timerMessage + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "timer"
}
```

I have an error and it says: "Parsing error: Unexpected token )"
I would really appreciate it if you would help me with my problem, Thanks!

(Btw I'm using it in Glitch on Google Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that there's an unexpected token `)` because you wrote your loop like this:

```js
for (i = 0, 10000000000) {...}
```

You forgot to add the third argument (usually `i++`). Also, if you want it to run 10000000000 times you should write a comparison:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {...}
```

I see what you're trying to achieve, but I would do it in a simpler way, using [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead of `setTimeout()`.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  timerMessage.edit(timerMessage + 1);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a right parenthesis after the setTimeout function. I am not entirely familiar with what you are doing, but I would try something like this :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
let timerMessage = await message.channel.send('0');

for (i = 0, 10000000000) {
   setTimeout(function()) { 
      timerMessage.edit(timerMessage + 1);
    }, 1000);
}

}

module.exports.help = {
   name: "timer";
}
```

Although this should (maybe) replace the missing parenthesis in your code, it seems to have many other issues. For example, your for loop does not make much sense. Normally a for loop would look something like this (to repeat a certain number of times in java) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.println(i);
} // will print numbers 0-9, repeat 10 times
```

The whole chunk of code with the setTimeout bit seems to be messed up... It would help to have a little more context on what you are trying to do / some commenting in your code.

If you are trying to get into coding, I'd recommend something much more basic or some tutorials. CodingTrain has great coding videos on youtube and you will learn a ton no matter what language you go with. Hope this helped...